# TelephonyManager Crashs on Android 10

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am getting the below stack trace in my Crashlytics for wide range of android 10 devices.
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Throwable android.os.ParcelableException.getCause()' on a null object reference

```
android.telephony.TelephonyManager$1.lambda$onError$2
android.telephony.TelephonyManager$1.lambda$onError$2 (TelephonyManager.java:5346)
android.telephony.-$$Lambda$TelephonyManager$1$DUDjwoHWG36BPTvbfvZqnIO3Y88.run (-.java:6)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

No Reference what part of app causing this but I am using TelephonyManager to get device MCC and MNC as below

```
  fun getMCCFromDevice(context: Context): String? {
    try {
        val tm = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        if (tm != null) {
            val networkOperator = tm!!.getNetworkOperator()
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(networkOperator)) {
                return networkOperator.substring(0, 3)
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return null

}

fun getMNCFromDevice(context: Context): String? {
    try {
        val tm = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        if (tm != null) {
            val networkOperator = tm!!.getNetworkOperator()
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(networkOperator)) {
                return networkOperator.substring(3) // Extract MNC part
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return null
}
```

Comment: It seems that Google has solved a similar issue but it's not clear on which versions: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141438333

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is due to accessing the `java.lang.Throwable android.os.ParcelableException.getCause()` method on this exception instance, **you should probably avoid calling `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block**, since internally it will invoke the `getCause()` method.